# sql - mysql not able to get desired result for group_concat, group by, transpose

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Giving you an example of problem I am facing creating mysql query. using group_concat or group by is not giving me the result I want.

Can anyone please tell me how can i achieve following results? If it can be solved using procedure or views, it is ok.

user

```
===============
| Id | UserId |
=====+========|
| 1  | 297    |
---------------
```

workex

```
=======================================================
| wid | UserId | title                      | company |
=====+========+===============+=======================|
| 1  | 297    | software engineer           | x       |
|----+--------+---------------+-----------------------|
| 2  | 297    | sr software engineer        | y       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

education

```
=========================================================
| eid | UserId | title                      | institute |
=====+========+===============+=========================|
| 1  | 297    | computer science            | p         |
|----+--------+---------------+-------------------------|
| 2  | 297    | MS software engineering     | q         |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Result

```
=====================================================================================================================================================================================
| userid  | workex_title                        | company | workex_title                | company | education                   | institute |education                   | institute |
=====+========+===============+======================================================================================================================================================|
| 297     | software engineer                   | x       | sr software engineer        | y       | computer science            | p         |sr software engineer        | q         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: make this table in php, because to create query for common case is imposible

Comment: What's the expected result if a user has only 1 education. Or 3?

Comment: Show the query you tried and Show the expected result

Comment: What 's kind of result do you want if each userid has 3 or more `workex` and `education` records?

Comment: @jarlh if user 'A' has 1 education and user 'B' has two show maximum column and display null or empty for user having less than maximum column

Comment: @Reno it is possible to have different combination for workex and education as each user has different # of workex and education